# How do I create a Google Apps Domain?

Tags: google-apps

How do I create a Google Apps Domain?

Probably I do not understand well what is meant by a 'Google Apps Domain'.
We do have a domain at the internet, but our people also have a gmail account each.
Mails send to the gmail account will be forwarded to their account at our domain and from there to their personal account.

I simply don't know how to get/create a Google Apps Domain.
Our orgaisation is non-profit and solely working with volunteers.
From posts at SO I deduce that you can do several things being an administrator of a Google Apps Domain, that are normal for administrators of a domain at a provider.

So I would like to have more info about Google Apps Domains including how to create them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information on what Google Apps is [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/72709). Google offer free accounts for non-profits via their [Google for Nonprofits site](http://www.google.com/nonprofits/products/).

Once you have an account, you'll have access to 24/7 phone support provided by the Google Enterprise Support team.

General information on signing up for an account is detailed in [this support article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926).